# iSCSI target implementation is User Space

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, block-device, iscsi

I want to write my own implementation of iSCSI target where in I want to interrupt read/write calls to block device and serve them from my custom storage implementation.
Is there any default library(preferably in GOLANG/Python) which gives this ability for an application running in user space.
Note: This implementation is similar to fuse but I want to avoid fuse and directly integrate my storage in iSCSI target implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I did a `iSCSI` target in user-space with `golang`, you may check it at [this link](https://github.com/gostor/gotgt)